# Knockout and Typescript with Model outside ViewModel not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, typescript

Ok, so if I do something like this with knockout it works perfectly

```
function UserModel()
{
  UserID = ko.observable();
  Name   = ko.observable();
}

function UserSettingsViewModel()
{
   var user = UserModel();
   this.Save = function(user) { SaveUser(user);};
}
ko.applyBindings(new UserSettingsViewModel());
```

Tried to do the same with typescript, but it doesn't really work

```
 declare var ko: any;

 interface IUser {
    UserID:    any;
    Username:  any;
    Name:      any;
    LastName:  any;
    CreatedOn: any;
    LastLogin: any;
    Picture:   any;  
 }

 class User implements IUser{

     UserID =   ko.observable('');
     Username = ko.observable('');
     Name     = ko.observable('');
     LastName = ko.observable('');
     CreatedOn= ko.observable('');
     LastLogin= ko.observable('');
     Picture  = ko.observable('');
 }

 function SaveUser(userSetting: any) : void
 {
     alert("I was saved!");
 }

 function EditUser(userSetting: any): void {
     alert("I was Edited!");
 }

 function DeleteUser(userSetting: any): void {
     alert("I was Deleted!");
 }

 class UserSettingsViewModel
 {

     userSetting: any;

     constructor()
     {
         this.userSetting = (<any>User)();
     }

     Save()
     {
             SaveUser(this.userSetting);
     }

     Delete()
     {
             DeleteUser(this.userSetting);
     }

     Edit()
     {
             EditUser(this.userSetting);
     }

 }

 window.onload = () => {
     var ViewModel = new UserSettingsViewModel();
     ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
 };
```

How can I do the same with TypeScript, I have tried different methos, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sneaky suspicion. You might have the wrong `this`. Use a lambda:

```
 function SaveUser(userSetting: any) : void
 {
     alert("I was saved!");
 }

 function EditUser(userSetting: any): void {
     alert("I was Edited!");
 }

 function DeleteUser(userSetting: any): void {
     alert("I was Deleted!");
 }

 class UserSettingsViewModel
 {

     userSetting: any;

     constructor()
     {
         this.userSetting = (<any>User)();
     }

     Save = () =>
     {
             SaveUser(this.userSetting);
     }

     Delete = () =>
     {
             DeleteUser(this.userSetting);
     }

     Edit = () =>
     {
             EditUser(this.userSetting);
     }

 }
```

More about `this` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Comment: It turns out my problem was in the HTML document, I had $root.Name, that's why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my code was right and working, what was wrong was my HTML document, I had $root.Name, and that's why it wasn't working, it works correctly now.